# Does a Sharepoint 2013 Online hosted Add-in have to create an app and app site?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-hosted-app, sharepoint-addin

Based on these Guides:

https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142379.aspx

Is it possible to create a SharePoint Online 2013 Hosted Add-in that only creates a web part without creating a new App and new App site?

Also, is it now possible to create web part user properties from client side code?

Comment: What makes you think there's no App Web in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142379.aspx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't confuse [Office Add-ins](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins)(your first link) and [SharePoint Add-ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142379.aspx)(your second link) they have absolutely nothing in common.

## Office Add-ins

Office Add-ins is a way to add capabilities to the Office clients (Word, Excel, PowerPoint, and Outlook) by having a manifest pointing to a web page (this could be a SharePoint page if you want it).

This requires a new "App", that really only is the manifest.
The manifest points to the same url for all usages in clients, so there is no concept of a app site. Which also means that if you want to store data from multiple users/companies, then you need to figure out how to keep them separated.

But there is also no concept of a web part in here.

## SharePoint Add-ins

SharePoint Add-ins is a way to add capabilites to SharePoint sites without creating security and performance problems (for the SharePoint site/server).

This requires a new "App" which is a zip-file with the extension .app, which contains at least a manifest file (but maybe more).

One of the ways a SharePoint Add-in can show information is by implementing a Client web part.

SharePoint Add-ins can be hosted in two ways:

### Provider Hosted

In a Provider Hosted add-in the manifest points to the same url(s) for all usages in sites, so there is no concept of a app site. Which also means that if you want to store data from sites, then you need to figure out how to keep them separated.

And you need to provide a hosting for the pages pointed to by the manifest somewhere. (And you might call this a app site)

### SharePoint Hosted

In a SharePoint Hosted add-in app file contains a wsp-file to create a app site and the manifest contains tokens so the url(s) are separate for each usage in sites. Which means that storing data separately is handled for you.

## App less web parts

If you want to implement a web part without creating an app and a separate site of any kind then you might want to look at some Client Side implementation like  [Widget Wrangler](https://github.com/Widget-Wrangler/ww) which was presented in this [Pnp Web Cast](https://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/OfficeDevPnP/PnP-Web-Cast-Introducing-Widget-Wrangler-for-SharePoint-development).

Comment: +1 for Widget Wrangler!

Comment: Thanks! An iframe-less, app-less widget model would be great, but if fully integrated into SPO web part, app catalog and even o365 app store features .  Something end users can deploy and share.  But in general SP API needs to get better and open more up to client side.  For example, why can't client side code easily add or change web part properties?  Also, is it just me or could SPO benefit from a built in, cloud based code IDE for pages, web parts and code block/widgets?  Embed Code, Script Editor and Content Editor leave a lot be desired.